# How to get enum name by value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript and I have an enum which looks like:

```
enum BookStatus {
  Accepted= 0,
  Started = 1,
  InProgress= 2,
  Submitted = 3,
  Rejected = 4,
}
```

How can I get the name as a string if I only have a numeric value?

For example, I get value `2`, I want to return string "InProgress", etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a numeric value, you can simply use `BookStatus[numericValue]` to retrieve the string value.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAQg9nA1gZQC4ENVgM5QN4CwAUFFAIIDGFwADqsACYC8UADADTGlroBO9DKCwCMnElACSIAAq84Ac17Bs2FgCYx3MACMIAS1QChUAMyaoAJWAArYBSMsALGIC+xYhTghsqKD8w4xmoA3B5e2HAANsAAdJEKABTwSDxY2ADa-mkAugCUwUA):

```
enum BookStatus {
  Accepted= 0,
  Started = 1,
  InProgress= 2,
  Submitted = 3,
  Rejected = 4,
}

const status = 2;
console.log(BookStatus[status]);
```